# Как заполнить массив числами от 100 до 0?

Tags: javascript

Мне необходимо создать переменную «start» = 100 и пустой массив «result». Затем создать цикл, который заполнит массив «result» значениями от 100 до 0 включительно при помощи декремента.

Мой код:

```
var start = 100;
var result = [];
while (start >= 0) {
    result.push(start--);
}
alert(result);
```

Comment: Какой такой отсчёт? Код цикла можно оптимизировать до `start = 0;`

Comment: в модульном окне начинает отминусовывать начиная с 99,а должен от 100.т.е первое число в модальном окне должно быть 100,далее 99,98,97 и т.д до ноля.А у меня начинает отсчет в модальном окне с 99,почему?

Comment: @АлександрМураховский Вы привели не весь код. В этом коде Вы получаете массив из 1 элемента и `start = 0;`

Comment: @АлександрМураховский в приведенном коде нет ни вашего окна ни хоть какого-нибудь вывода, поэтоу сказать сложно, разве только то, что скорее всего вывод осуществляется после декремента

Comment: вы наверно проверку на число делаете ПОСЛЕ `start--;`..а нужно ДО

Comment: Выложи весь код

Comment: Весь код не надо, но нам определённо нужен [mcve]

Comment: @vp_arth как мы можем наблюдать сейчас, минимальный самодостаточный пример у автора сделать не получилось)

Comment: @andreymal но не воспроизводимый)

Comment: Вот такое задание:1.Создать переменную«start» = 100 и пустой массив «result».2.Создать цикл,который заполнит массив «result» значениями от 100 до 0 включительно при помощи декремента.

Comment: Наберитесь терпения, человек первый день на проекте.

Comment: Александр, вот этот комментарий добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @АлександрМураховский задание хорошо, но ваш код в вопросе не содержит ошибок или проблем, которые вы указали, а значит помочь не с чем, либо вам надо показать весь код который вы писали

Comment: Быстро заполнить массив одинаковыми значениями:
new Array(36).fill(/\W/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    // 1.Создать переменную«start» = 100 и пустой массив «result».
    var start = 100;
    var result = [];
    // 2.Создать цикл,который заполнит массив «result» значениями от 100 до 0 включительно при помощи декремента.
    while (start >= 0) {
      result.push(start--);
    }
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: выводит сразу все цифры.а должен считать при каждом нажатии на кнопку "ок",т.е от 100-0 включительно.

Comment: Я сдаюсь, Ваше тех.задание слишком быстро меняется.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!Ваш код мне помог,все правильно!!

Answer (score 2):

Довольно извращенный и медленный способ, но в одно выражение, просто забавы ради.
Создает массив, заполненный значениями от 0 до 99:

```
(new Array(100)).fill(1).map((a,i)=>i)
[].map.call('_'.repeat(100), (a,i)=>i)
```

Соответственно этот код создаст массив, заполненный значениями от 100 до 0:

```
(new Array(101)).fill(1).map((a,i)=>i).reverse()
[].map.call('_'.repeat(101), (a,i)=>i).reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = 100;
var result = [];
for(start;start>=0;start--){
    result.push(start--);
}
```

Comment: постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ: [edit]